# Java BufferedReader readline calculate values from file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, filereader

I am new to Java and at the moment lost.

I have this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

/**
 *
 * @author Darwish
 */
public class M3UReader {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static boolean isValidHeader(String playList)
    {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        BufferedReader br;
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(playList)));
            String s = br.readLine(); // declares the variable "s"
            if(s.startsWith("#EXTM3U")) { // checks the line for this keyword
                returnValue = true; // if its found, return true
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("isValidHeader:: error with file "+ playList + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
    public static int getNumberOfTracks(String playList)
    {
        int numberOfTracks = 0; // sets the default value to zero "0"
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(playList)));
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine())!=null) // if "s" first line is not null
            {
                if(s.startsWith("#")==false) { // if the first line starts with "#" equals to false. 
                    numberOfTracks++; // increments
                }
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            numberOfTracks = -1; // chek if the file doesnt exist 
            System.err.println("could not open/read line from/close filename "+ playList);
        }
        return numberOfTracks;

    }

    public static int getTotalMinutes(String playList)
    {
        // code needed here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String filename = "files\\playlist.m3u"; // finds the file to read (filename <- variable declaration.) 
        boolean isHeaderValid = M3UReader.isValidHeader(filename); // declares the variabe isHeaderValid and links it with the class isValidHeader
        System.out.println(filename + "header tested as "+ isHeaderValid); // outputs the results

        if(isHeaderValid)
        {
            int numOfTracks = M3UReader.getNumberOfTracks(filename);
            System.out.println(filename + " has "+ numOfTracks + " tracks ");
        }

    }
}
```

On the method getTotalMinutes, I have to find a way to calculate the totals of the int values that was read from the file. The File has this data:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:537,Banco De Gaia - Drippy F:\SortedMusic\Electronic\Banco De Gaia\Big Men Cry\01 Drippy.mp3
#EXTINF:757,Banco De Gaia - Celestine F:\SortedMusic\Electronic\Banco De Gaia\Big Men Cry\02 Celestine.mp3
#EXTINF:565,Banco De Gaia - Drunk As A Monk F:\SortedMusic\Electronic\Banco De Gaia\Big Men Cry\03 Drunk As A Monk.mp3
#EXTINF:369,Banco De Gaia - Big Men Cry F:\SortedMusic\Electronic\Banco De Gaia\Big Men Cry\04 Big Men Cry.mp3
```

The number after the #EXTINF: is the length of the music which from the data above is in seconds.

I don't know what code to write on the getTotalMinutes method to get the program to read the minutes from the file and then calculate all of them to get the total of minutes. I searched the web on how to do this unfortunately I can't find any. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: What does *"length of the music"* mean?  Minutes, seconds, ticks, tocks, tim-tams?

Comment: the length of the music is in seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, its just copy of your getNumberTracks method but it is parsing the file the way you need to get total minutes :

```
public static final String beginning = "#EXTINF:";
public static final String afterNumber = ",";

public static int getTotalMinutes(String playList) {
    int value = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(playList)));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) // if "s" first line is not null
        {
            if (s.contains(beginning)) {
                String numberInString = s.substring(beginning.length(), s.indexOf(afterNumber));
                value += Integer.valueOf(numberInString);
            }
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: wow this solves my problem thanks! Now I need to find a way to put everything in the getTotalMinutes method :)

I have thought of using s.contains but I dont know what to put inside the (). I tried to use %d unfortunately it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the description provided from [here](http://www.assistanttools.com/articles/m3u_playlist_format.shtml), the numeric value is the number of seconds.

So, given a `String` in the format of `#EXTINF:{d},{t}` you should be able to use simple `String` manipulation to get the value out...

```
String text = "#EXTINF:537,Banco De Gaia - Drippy F:\\SortedMusic\\Electronic\\Banco De Gaia\\Big Men Cry\\01 Drippy.mp3";
String durationText = text.substring(text.indexOf(":") + 1, text.indexOf(","));
int durationSeconds = Integer.parseInt(durationText);
System.out.println(durationSeconds);
```

Which will print `537`...

Next we just need to do some simple time arithmetic...

```
double seconds = durationSeconds;
int hours = (int)(seconds / (60 * 60));
seconds = seconds % (60 * 60);
int minutes = (int)(seconds / 60);
seconds = seconds % (60);

System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(seconds));
```

Which prints `0:8:57` (or 8 minutes and 57 seconds)

Comment: thanks for your input. I have managed to get the seconds into minutes with the help of user2854908's code:

int numOfMinutes = M3UReader.getTotalMinutes(filename);
System.out.println(filename + " has "+ numOfTracks + " tracks, " + (numOfMinutes/60) + " minutes in total ");

Answer (score 0):

To read M3U files you'll want to search for information about M3U parsers. There are already many efficient open source parsers available, but you will need to pay close attention to their licenses if you are planning on selling or distributing this.

M3u Parser looks like promising if you just want something quick and efficient.

[M3u Parser](http://code.google.com/p/java-m3u-file-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int getTotalMinutes(String filename) {
    int totalSeconds = 0;

    if (isValidHeader(filename)) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));) {
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //If the next line is metadata it should be possible to extract the length of the song
                if (nextLine.startsWith(M3U_METADATA)) {
                    int i1 = nextLine.indexOf(":");
                    int i2 = nextLine.indexOf(",");
                    String substr = nextLine.substring(i1 + 1, i2);
                    totalSeconds += Integer.parseInt(substr);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | NumberFormatException e) {
            //Exception caught - set totalSeconds to 0
            System.err.println("getTotalSeconds:: error with file " + filename + ": " + e.getMessage());
            totalSeconds = 0;
        }
    }

    return totalSeconds;
}
```